# Was Tracy secretly taking serum in "Thunder Force"?

Tags: thunder-force

In the 2021 film *[Thunder Force](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt10121392/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)*, Lydia and Emily receive superpowers from an experimental treatment.

Lydia receives daily injections, while Emily has to take a daily tablet. Lydia's treatment takes 33 days and while it's not very specific Emily's treatment takes slightly less.

At the end of the film, Tracy also has superpowers.

With it taking around a month for Emily and Lydia to gain superpowers, has Tracy been undergoing treatment all this time, or has she created a faster acting treatment?